# How do you position a PageView inside a Stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview, flutter-positioned

I have a `PageView` and a button inside a `Stack` (the `PageView` is at the bottom of the `Stack`). I have the button in the `bottomCenter` using `Stack`'s `alignment` property.

I want to position the `PageView` inside the `Stack` so that it appears above the button (as in vertically above, not above in the `Stack`). However, it seems that you can't use the `Positioned` widget with a `PageView` to accomplish this.

I am using a `Stack` because the `PageView` contains a zoomable widget using `InteractiveViewer`, and I want the button to stay on top when this widget is zoomed in.

Wrapping the `PageView` with a `Positioned` widget gives different errors based on if you run the app from scratch, if you do a Flutter Hot Restart, or if you do a Flutter Hot Reload. (However, there are no errors if you do not specify any of the other `Positioned` parameters, i.e. `bottom`, `left`, etc.)

Another problem that occurs when you hot reload is that it does do something to the `PageView`. It shifts it up, but by more than the specified amount in the `bottom` parameter. It also cuts off a lot of the width (but doesn't give any overflow errors). You can see this in the second picture that is included.

If you specify the `bottom` parameter and then do a hot reload it gives this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough horizontal space for the children. In this case, consider using a Row instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the width of the viewport to the sum of the widths of its children.
```

If you specify the `bottom` parameter, then either stop and run the app from scratch or do a hot restart, it gives these errors:

Error 1:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during performLayout():
The method 'toStringAsFixed' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toStringAsFixed(1)
```

Error 2 (several variations of this error):

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#99b5a relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Here is a simple app that shows my problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TopToolbar(currentIndex == 0
                ? 'Car'
                : currentIndex == 1
                    ? 'Bike'
                    : 'Walk'),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv Specifying this causes the errors: vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                    bottom: 50, // 50 because that is the height of the button
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      onPageChanged: (page) {
                        setState(() {
                          currentIndex = page;
                        });
                      },
                      children: [
                        CarScreen(),
                        BikeScreen(),
                        WalkScreen(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      height: 50, // <-------------------- Height of the button
                      color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                      child: Text('A button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
// ==== I don't think the code below is relevant to the question, but who knows:
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = value;
            _pageController.jumpToPage(value);
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car), label: 'Car'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike), label: 'Bike'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.directions_walk), label: 'Walk'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopToolbar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  TopToolbar(this.label);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text('Custom toolbar for $label', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

class CarScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ScreenWidget('Car');
}

class BikeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ScreenWidget('Bike');
}

class WalkScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ScreenWidget('Walk');
}

class ScreenWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  ScreenWidget(this.title);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Center(
      child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 550,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text('$title Screen', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))));
}
```

What it looks like without the `bottom` parameter specified. See that the button covers up part of the `PageView`, I don't want this to happen, this is what I'm trying to fix:

[image: bottom not specified]

What it looks like when you specify the `bottom` parameter and then do a hot reload. You can see it shifts it up by more than what's specified by `bottom`, and it cuts off a lot of the width without giving overflow errors:

[image: bottom specified then hot reload]

What it looks like when you specify the `bottom` parameter and then either hot restart, or stop and run the app from scratch. The `PageView` and the button are gone:

[image: bottom specified then either hot restart or stop and run from scratch]

Comment: Have you tried using a `FloatingActionButton`? How is that different from what you want this button to do? Also, do try playing with the `fit` property of the `Stack`

Comment: A `FloatingActionButton` wouldn't be good for my purpose. The `CarScreen()` equivalent in my actual app takes up most of the screen, and I need to put words in the button, not just an icon. I did play around with the `fit` property of the `Stack`, but it didn't help any.

Comment: With [this constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/FloatingActionButton.extended.html) you can give both a label Widget and icon Widget to the FloatingActionButton. Also, remember all UI components are widgets. You can put anything in a FloatingActionButton.